# Chromium based browsers load pages so slow

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, chromium

All chromium based browsers such as chrome edge … on my windows 7 PC load pages so slow I should wait one minute for every single page, my system spec is Pentium 4,ram 768.

Comment: Maybe you have a load of a lot of extensions. You may try to remove some if you not like. And why you are using Chromium Edge on Windows 7? It is for Windows 10, I am not sure it will work properly on Windows 7. Also try to update chrome to latest version (v84.0) and flush your DNS cache.

Comment: which page exactly, what browser, what version? how did you install it (with any extensions)? Do you have a different device on the same network that can do it faster if yes what is it?

Comment: @Wasif Hasan I haven't any extensions installed; I said both edge and chrome, edge is published for windows 7 too.chrome is the latest version. How to flush dns cache?

Comment: @Albin All pages, chrome and edge and opera and …, Latest versions, I installed them with official installer, They haven't any extensions installed, Yes, almost all other devices load pages so fast also IE 11 loads pages so fast

Comment: Chrome is memory intensive, you don't have near enough memory installed.

Comment: @Moab What to do? What is alternative?

Comment: Add more memory to your motherboard

Comment: @Moab Post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is a very memory intensive program, you don't have near enough memory installed for it to run fast.